# TFS remove all workspace on local

Tags: tfs

Today I want to clean all workspace on our build server.
But I tried some command param and failed.

How to remove all TFS workspace on local?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After search, following cmd will remove all workspaces:

```
tf workspaces /remove:*
```

Refs:

[What’s the difference between tf workspace /delete and tf workspaces /remove?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2008/10/14/what-s-the-difference-between-tf-workspace-delete-and-tf-workspaces-remove.aspx)

[TFS – deleting old workspaces](http://gergelyorosz.com/2009/01/tfs-deleting-old-workspaces/)